# rails download file if I know file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have read some questions like  this [Rails download file from show action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028689/rails-download-file-from-show-action), but there are kind of confusing me.
I have file terms.docx. It is completely public. I want to show user a link to download it (for example `<a href="/terms.docx"> Terms and conditions</a>`)
I can put it in public folder if needed but I can't find this folder  in my rails project.

So How do I do this?

Comment: by default rails generates one in root of project directory.

Comment: @Nithin i found it thanks, so what do I do? just put file there?

Comment: create a dir and add it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, just put file in the public folder which is located in root folder as `@Nithin` said and

```
<a href="/terms.docx"> Terms and conditions</a>
```

Will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you can add:

```
<%= link_to "Terms and conditions", "/terms.docx" %>
```

**In this case, the 'terms.docx' file should be placed in your public directory.**

This will generate the link:

```
<a href="/terms.docx"> Terms and conditions</a>
```